# Cannot create an URI file from text-to-speech audio on UWP

Tags: c#, audio, uwp, text-to-speech

I was trying to create a toast notification with text-to-speech as the audio notification. When user type a description like "Let's eat" and save the toast, when the time is come the toast will say "Let's eat". It like an ringtone for toast.

I got the answer from [Social MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/00746420-cf2f-46f7-b8a3-a7289a6de0cf/uwpccan-we-access-uri-from-void?forum=wpdevelop) how to create an toast notification from text-to-speech, but at my program it always turn to exception.

This is the code for creating text-to-speech toast notification:

```
 private static async Task<Uri> AudioforToast(string text)
    {
        var voices = SpeechSynthesizer.AllVoices;
        using (var synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer())
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            {
                try
                {
                    synthesizer.Voice = voices.First(gender => gender.Gender == VoiceGender.Female);

                    // Create a stream from the text.
                    SpeechSynthesisStream synthesisStream = await synthesizer.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(text);

                    // And now write that to a file
                    var file = await ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.CreateFileAsync("ToastAudio", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
                    using (var fileStream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
                    {
                        await synthesisStream.AsStream().CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                    }

                    // And then return the file path
                    return new Uri("ms-appdata:///temp/ToastAudio");
                }

                catch (Exception)
                {
                    // If the text is unable to be synthesized, throw an error message to the user.            
                    var messageDialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Unable to synthesize text. Toast Audio is default");
                    await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
                }
            }
        }

        // If the text is unable to be synthesized, don't return a custom sound
        return null;
    }
```

When I tried to debug it, the code cannot save the text-to-speech result into file.

This audio later will be use as a custom audio for toast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I tried to debug it, the code cannot save the text-to-speech result into file.

I've tested your code in my side. I got the exception "the stream doesn't support write", so the question was very obvious. In your code, you just open stream for read `file.OpenStreamForReadAsync()` You should use `file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync()`Then it will work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After I change into OpenStreamForWriteAsync(), it go to try section, but still the text-to-speech isn't come out.

Comment: @OliviaOlgaClarissa I have contacted with the relevant team. For now, it doesn’t support temp folder. You could copy audio file to local folder. We'll consider adding support for the temp folder in a future version of Windows.